# logistic regression debugging tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I am trying to learn tensorflow and are currently trying to do a simple logistic regression model. Here is my code I stitched together from diffrent examples I could find.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Training data
    input = tf.constant(tra)
    target = tf.constant(np.transpose(data[:,1]).astype(np.float64))

    # Set model weights
    W = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(10, 1).astype(np.float64))

    # Construct model
    mat=tf.matmul(input,W)
    pred = tf.sigmoid(mat)

    # Compute the error
    yerror = tf.sub(pred, target)
    # We are going to minimize the L2 loss. The L2 loss is the sum of the
    # squared error for all our estimates of y. This penalizes large errors
    # a lot, but small errors only a little.
    loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(yerror)

    # Gradient Descent
    update_weights = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

    # Initializing the variables
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    for _ in range(50):
        # Repeatedly run the operations, updating the TensorFlow variable.
        sess.run(update_weights)

        print(loss.eval())
```

So the code runs but the error dose not improve after each 'sess.run(update_weights)' itteration and I have tried with diffrent step sizes.

I wonder if the setup is corret?

I am a bit unsure how to debugg it since the the calculation of everything is done at the run command. The traning data is fine. If some of you could see what I am doing wrong in this whole session build up or give suggestions on how I can debugg this.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I did some testing around and found that it had problems with the dimensions of the 'target' variable. I had to specifi that it was a m x 1 matrix (where m is the number of traning examples) this is done with specifying the shape to the constant variable:

```
target = tf.constant(np.transpose(data[:,1]).astype(np.float64), shape=[m,1])
```

also the gradiant decent did not do so well until i normalized the features.

Answer (score 0):

While what you are doing is a reasonable thing to do for regression, this probably won't work well in a classification task. Also, this is not what is typically intended as logistic regression. For logistic regression, you maximize the `log prob(correct label|input)` summed over all data samples. This is done conveniently by having a softmax layer.

There are useful mathematical properties that come with it, that help debugging. For instance, if you input is totally random, then the loss should be `log (N)`. If you set all weights to zero, then that should be the loss. If you label samples, say `1/3` positive, and `2/3` negative in a binary classification, then a model which doesn't take any input into account (just a bias term) should just return `log(2/3)`, so you can debug what you are getting to some extent.

Comment: Thanks for comment some questions:
Can I put any random numbers or should it be random guassian with mean 0 and std 1? and are the N in log(N) the number of features I have or number of traning examples?

Comment: If the weights are all zero, it doesn't really matter what the weights are, but otherwise yes, you can feed anything that's uncorrelated with the output. The `N` refers to the number of classes.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow is now shipped with a builtin debugger called *tfdbg*. It exposes the intermediate tensor values and present them through a command-line interface. It should make it easier for you to debug your code. Please take a look at the documentation (at master HEAD) at:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/debugger/index.md